# What is my error with my Feed in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

My feed url is (http://www.robertstikmanz.com/feed/rss/) yet it's showing a very weird layout. What exactly am i doing wrong, or what do I need to set in my server/installation to make this work correctly?

Fixed:
It looks like this (http://screencast.com/t/Yjc2YmRmNW) in Chrome on Mac yet not on every other Browser. This is why I was confused :)

Comment: I dont see anything wrong it. It works fine for me

Comment: Your RSS feed doesn't have a layout. It's just XML.

Answer (score 0):

Might be that you're using the wrong feed URL and/or have a RSS plugin working against you.

mydomain.com/feed/ is the default wordpress feed URL.

/feed/ shows full text of posts and your sharing links, /feed/rss/ doesn't.

Comment: this is on a fresh WP install with no other plugins.

I am using the (http://www.robertstikmanz.com/?feed=rss) url which should work fine. I'm confused :)

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the layout issues you're seeing?

Comment: found the reason = Chrome doesn't like it